# Execute a colorized command from a php script

Tags: php, colors, command, command-line-interface

I have a command, for example 'git diff' that output a colorized result when I run it from the terminal.

Now, I want to call that command from a CLI php script and display in the console the colorized result. I have try with exec(), system(), passthru() but in all case the output has been converted to plain black and white text.

Is there a way to preserve the color of the standard result? If not, does someone know why this information get lost?

Comment: Just an idea: it's probably environment-variable related. A quick test might provide clues: `env > env_a.out && php -r 'system("env");' > env_b.out && diff env_a.out env_b.out`

Comment: I try your test, once both env file reordered, the diff is only like this: 'SHLVL=1 against SHLVL=2'

Comment: That similar? I'm surprised to be honest. Perhaps providing further detail about your environment would be helpful in your question, as well as simplifying the problem by trying to output a color yourself first (`php -r 'printf("%c[32mGreen%c[0m\n", 27, 27);'`) rather than from invoking a command like git.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In all likelihood the command you are running is checking to see if output is to a terminal and not colorizing it if it isn't.  There is usually a way to force it, but that's going to be specific to the command itself; in the case of `git diff`, you can specify `--color=always`.

Comment: Yes, your are right, if I did something like that:
`<?php system('git diff --color=always'); ?>`
I got the color.
So the question now is: Is there a way, from php, to tell the commands that yes, we are in a terminal?

Comment: Unfortunately, the command really *isn't* attached to a terminal the way PHP executes it (unlike the way the shell does).  Even when you use `passthru`, PHP places itself in between the command and the terminal; it just doesn't modify the output as it passes through.  It's not just colors; full-screen commands will simply not work at all when run this way.  So short of some elaborate pseudo-terminal setup, which I don't think you can do from PHP anyway, I don't think there's a general solution.