# How to capture STDIO with color in PHP?

Tags: php, shell, stdin, xterm

Some CLI binaries output has xterm colored text, but either `shell_exec`, `exec` and the backtick operators only returns a text-only version of the output.

How can I capture the output along with xterm color codes?

Comment: That does not solve my problem, but I get the answer.

Comment: The suggested duplicate does not address this question.

Comment: If the duplicate shouldn't answer your question, then explain very detailed **how** it fails to do so. Just saying "doesn't work" isn't a sufficient differentiation. (And btw, even if it doesn't work, it's still the same topic. Throw a bounty and a concrete example on the duplicate then. No example = no more concrete help.)

Comment: The duplicate does logically include my question, and the answers there suggest that there is no proper way to do what I was asking for. So I cannot say it is solved, but I get the answer that I have to figure out other means to achieve that.

Comment: Specifically [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148151/execute-a-colorized-command-from-a-php-script#comment13079589_10159827) answers my question.